# Verify a tree whether it is Binomial tree

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, ocaml

I believe that for a tree to be a binomial tree, it must satisfy the requirement that a tree of r node has r children. 
I define my node to be a tuple of rank, element, and a binomial tree list.

I am not sure how to check whether a tree is a binomial tree. All I can think of is to make a recursive function that implements:

1. If a tree of rank 0 and an empty list, then it is true that it is a binomial tree.
2. If a tree of rank r, then I somehow need to check whether my tree is consisted of other trees of ranks r-1,r-2,...,0. Am I on the right track here? I am stuck at this point.
   Here is what I have got so far:

   ```
    let valid_rank (Tree : tree) : bool = 
      let curr_rank = (rank Tree) in
        let rec helper t counter =
          match t with
           |Node(r,x,c) -> (if  r <> (curr_rank - counter) then false
                           else (match c with
                                   |[] -> true
                                   |t1::ts -> helper t1 (counter + 1)))
                            in helper Tree 0

    let verify_Bintree (t : tree) : bool = 
      (valid_rank t)
   ```

   My point here is that in my valid_rank function, when I "match c with..." at the end, I recursively call helper on t1 and not on the rest of the list ts because helper takes in a tree, not a tree list. I am not sure this will work.

My purpose here is that for a tree of, say rank 3, then I want to know whether it has all of the subchildren with ranks 2,1,0. If yes, then it is a binomial tree.

Do you think my valid_rank function is flawed? If so, how can I fix my algorithm?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're not sure what defines a binomial tree, make sure you understand before attempting to write a function that check s whether a tree is binomial. What code do you have so far?

Comment: What is a binomial tree? That isn't a standard term when used the way that you seem to be using it. Do you mean "binary tree"?

Comment: You definitely want to know what a binomial tree is before going any further :-) I see a definition on page 21 of Okasaki, "Purely Functional Data Structures". A rank 0 binomial tree is a single node. A rank (r + 1) binomial tree consists of two rank r binomial trees linked so that one is the leftmost child of the other. Possibly this is what you're dealing with.

Comment: @eclecticist I do not want to post my code in public but all I have at the moment (just the ideas) that I need helper functions to check whether the ranks in order, whether all the ranks exist and whether the min heap property is obeyed. I am still at the early stage of this problem.

Comment: @AdamRalphus "I do not want to post my code in public" well, then we cannot help you, can we?

Comment: @mb21 Ok I will post my code.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield your thought, please

Comment: @AdamRalphus I don't know ocaml that well, but looks like you didn't post the definition of the `Tree` type? Also, as mentioned the terms `rank` and `binomial` tree have multiple meanings.... is this homework? if so maybe it's best if you ask your teaching assistent... or post all the necessary parts of the assignment, so we can help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binomial tree for rang N is one that has N children of range N-1, N-2, ..., 0 that are each  binomial trees. You are on the right track but got somewhat off course.

The helper should check that each element of `c` has the expected rang and is a valid binomial tree (recurse to the main function). So the helper should be something like this

```
let Node(curr_rank, x, c) = tree in
let rec helper counter = function
   | [] -> counter = -1
   | n::ns -> if counter = rank n
              then if valid_rank n
                   then helper (counter - 1) ns
                   else false
              else false
in helper (curr_rank - 1) c
```